# Where and how should I add/link the manifest.json file? In index.php or sw.js file, its currently sitting in src/ folder?

Tags: php, progressive-web-apps, manifest.json

I am trying to convert my PWA website into installable application using PWAbuilder.com - It looks like when I try to scan my website it does not sees a manifest.json file. Manifest.json file exists  in the src/ folder as opposed to being in the parent folder.

My question is how and where should I add the link to manifest.json file in index.php or sw.js so that PWAbuilder.com can recognize it.

Refer screenshot for the file structure of my website and here is the error report
[image: Screenshot]

I tried moving the manifest.json file to parent directory and that breaks the site completely showing error that Apache server error - ht.access is unable to load the website.

Please help.

Comment: You should be able to answer the question by yourself. Which language is PHP and which language is sw.js?

Comment: Thanks for your response I am still learning and so would appreciate any help in this regards.

Comment: JS == JavaScript. So where does a JSON (JavaScript Object Notation) file go?